# How to call a normal controller method in ActiveAdmin?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, namespaces, ruby-on-rails-3.1, activeadmin

I'm using ActiveAdmin for a `Products` model.

In my `ProductsController` I'm doing some special magic in the `update` method that I'd like to also happen when updating the product from ActiveAdmin. In order to DRY, I'd like to call the `ProductsController.update` method from ActiveAdmin. I tried:

```
controller do
  def update
    ProductsController.update
  end
end
```

But I get a `NoMethodError in Admin::PoisController#update`. So apparently ActiveAdmin's namespace is still applied. How can I refer to Controllers outside that namespace?

Answer (score 2):

You are definitely still in the namespace. Call it `::ProductsController` to get the global one. But you're not done then.

The controller actions in Rails are not a class methods, but instance methods. You'd have to instantiate the controller to call an action. You could try it, but I don't think it'll work.

I would extract the logic from the original `ProductsController` so it can be called easily from both controllers.

Comment: OK, good idea to put the code into a common class. I tried to put it in `ProductsHelper` and I can call it successfully from my `ProductsController` by including `ProductsHelper` first. However, I found no way to include it in ActiveAdmin. Their DSL doesn't seem to support `include`.